# How to make fast count() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, count

I have two tables. First table(`NESNE` table) is main table that I am searching on and has info of books. Second table (`ciltkopya` table) has volumes of books. So One book can have 1,2,3.. and more volumes. I want to show that how much volumes on database. I have following query and it works. But it is `slow`. How can I make `fast` it?

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM nesne n 
LEFT JOIN ciltkopya c ON n.id = c.nesne_id
WHERE MATCH(`n.formdata`) AGAINST('world' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

When I query `EXPLAIN` my query, following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCef.png

---

OK I figure out it. Solution:

> SELECT count(c.nesne_id) FROM ciltkopya c JOIN (SELECT id FROM nesne WHERE MATCH(formdata) AGAINST('world' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) n ON n.id = c.nesne_id

Thaks :)

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: Please show your table definitions, including indexes. How fast is the query? How many rows, approximately, in each table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `formdata` is in `c`, I would start by changing the `left join` to an `inner join`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM nesne n JOIN
     ciltkopya c
     ON n.id = c.nesne_id
WHERE MATCH(c.formdata) AGAINST('world' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Second, I would question whether the `join` is needed at all.  This may do what you want:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ciltkopya c
WHERE MATCH(c.formdata) AGAINST('world' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If `formdata` is really in `n`, then you probably don't need the `join` at all.